# Проблема с background-image

Tags: html, css, background-image

По какой-то причине картинка не вставляется, путь точно верный.

Div, фон которого - картинка(должна быть)

```
<div class="first"> 
                <h1 class="company">Наша компания</h1>  
            </div>
```

css div-а

```
.first {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url(...img/about.jpg);
     
}
```

Comment: Три точки в url(...img/about.jpg); это верный путь?

Comment: Нет, я их сейчас убрал, всё равно. Консоль выдаёт ошибку "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" Я даже полный путь прописывал

Comment: Замените ```...``` на ```../```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Здравствуйте!** Попробуйте поставить `z-index` у `div` в css на `-1`, что-то по типу такого:

```
.first {
z-index: -1;
}
```

Если же не получится, то попробуйте создать новый элемент `img` с `src` вашего изображения, по типу такого:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Image</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="first"> 
   <img id="backimg" src="..img/about.jpg" style="position: absolute;z-index: -1;">
   <h1 class="company">Наша компания</h1>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Стили я указал в самом элементы, но если вам угодно то перенесите их в ваш css файл.
Как у меня это выглядит(src изменён для наглядности):
[image: CSS Example]

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Нет спасибо лучше, чем нажать кнопку **upvote** 